# Is SQL really a programming language after all?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm presenting a portfolio of the languages I've mastered, but here's a thing I shouldn't be asking really; is SQL a literal programming language or is it not? A lot of people say it is definitely one, others completely disagree.

Comment: It's a query language, A *declarative* query language. But that's just a technicality. Most people will consider it a programming language. For your resumé I would add it as a programming language, but in an interview I would make the difference just to be pedantic ;-)

Comment: How do you define a *programming language* after all? It's certainly worthy including in a portfolio, no matter the answer.

Comment: SQL is considered a fourth generation computer language, because it provides a level of abstraction independent of computer hardware (roughly relational algebra).

Comment: So not a programming language after all? If it is a domain specific one, does that prevent it from being a programming language like others?

Comment: I'd defenitely count it as a programming language in the sense it helps you codify and execute problems, data problems in this case. For a portfolio of languages (for a resume?) I'd defenitely count it as it is a valuable skill.

Answer (score 4):

SQL is considered to be a [Fourth Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language) computer language.  The first three are basically:

1. Machine code.
2. Assembly code.
3. Common general-purpose languages, such as C, C++, Java, Python, and so on.

So, based on a commonly used definition in computer science it is a programming language.  And SQL is a prime example of an entire class of languages (and perhaps the most widely used of that class).

A related question is whether SQL is [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) -- that is can SQL emulate a Turing Machine.  I should emphasize that this is really a theoretical question: no finite machine is really Turing complete.

I actually never studied this in depth, but I have read that the original SQL was Turing Incomplete.  Only the addition of recursive CTEs makes it complete (well, I guess recursive user-defined functions might also serve this purpose).

Comment: @xdraxulis . . . You can use words like Humpty Dumpty to mean what YOU say they mean.  I'm simply pointing out that computer science traditionally defines computer languages in such a way that SQL is included.  Whether or not Python is considered 4GL is probably somewhat a matter of debate.  Personally, I think there is a missing grouping to include more advanced features, such as being object-oriented.

Answer (score -1):

SQL is a Language! A Query Language!
More than a programming Language, It is a Query Language.
Even for asking a Query of your concern for an Answer/clarity, we need a language. The platform we use for asking(input) to existing data is MySQL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).